# A distribution such that these expectation are 'closed-form'

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

I am seeking a continuous distribution with real positive support for the random variable $X$ such that, for all $t \in \mathbb R_{+}$,

$$\mathbb E \left(\ln\left(1+tX\right)\right)$$ is given in a 'nice enough' closed form.

My first guesses were an exponential, a lognormal, but nothing worked properly. Of course 'nice enough' is not properly defined... This should be a function of $t$ that is, e.g, not an infinite serie, such that it is easy to compute with a computer.

To sum up, the conditions i have are :

- The distribution must be continuous and positive
- The expression of the expectation must be closed form.

Do you happend to know such a distribution ?

Comment: As you say, thisis not a well defined question.  Given the artificiality of the question, what makes it interesting should be the usefulness of the answer.  What is the usefulness of the answer?

Comment: Well, the usefullness is hard to describe in a few lines hahaha. Sorry about that. Basicaly this distribution will serve as a computational pivotal in some broader problem. If it exists.

Comment: How about the [Beta prime distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_prime_distribution) for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ positive integers? In the simplest case $\alpha=\beta=1$ we have $\mathbb{E}\ln(1+t X) = (t \ln t)/(t-1)$.

Comment: Yeah @TimothyBudd, this works. very usefull finding, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

For instance, for $X$ with pdf $f(x)=1(x>0)/(1+x)^2$, by integration by parts, the expectation in question is $t\ln t/(t-1)$ for $t\in(0,\infty)\setminus\{1\}$, and it is $1$ for $t=1$.

More generally, explicit results obtain for any $X$ with a cdf $F$ rational on $[0,\infty)$; for instance, one may take $F(x)=\big(\frac{p(x)}{1+p(x)}\big)^k\,1(x\ge0)$, where $p$ is any nonzero polynomial with nonnegative coefficients and $k$ is a natural number.
In the above example, $F(x)=x/(1+x)$ for $x\ge0$.

Comment: Usefull example, thanks :)

Comment: Also suggested by @TimothyBudd around the same time in a [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/373404/a-distribution-such-that-these-expectation-are-closed-form#comment945063_373404).

Comment: @LSpice : Thank you for your comment. Indeed, the first paragraph of my answer (based on the idea expressed later in the second paragraph of the answer) appeared just a minute before Timothy Budd's comment.